# Replace data after angle brackets

Tags: linux

[UDP Image which need to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNjlW.jpg)I have  udp , would like to change udp to tcp inside my config file , can someone please help me here.

sed 's/udp/tcp/'   /config path/

Regards
Dev

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/udp/tcp/g' path/to/filename
```

g for global

-i modify the file inplace

If you want to backup the original file:

```
sed -i.bak 's/udp/tcp/g' path/to/filename
```

Comment: Have attached the image I do have the data after angle brackets.

Comment: @Deb thank you. You need to also add -i in front in order to modify the file.

Comment: @Deb, I am happy that I could help. Could you please upvote and mark my answer as the solution?